# What exactly is changing in events.list API after upcoming changes to the Google Calendar API v3 11 March 2024?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

As per Google, following changes are being made to event.list for Calendar

- Events.list: Specify the event types you need for your application as a parameter. Without making this change, working location events will start to be returned.

Currently, if we don't specify eventType, we get ["default", "focusTime", "outOfOffice"] events by default

What will be changed in the Events.list response after 11 March ? Will it return only "Working Location" event type by default, or will it return an additional type along with the existing 3 types i.e ["default", "focusTime", "outOfOffice", "workingLocation]

Comment: Please include a link to wherever it states that there are coming changes

Comment: Please visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) and click on Release Notes. It will show upcoming changes.